# Android Barcode Scanner Not reading some barcodes

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on a Project which uses the Barcode Scanner for  redeem points. I have tried Zxing,QR Droid, Red Laser,Scan Life,Shop Savy etc usig HTC EVO 3D. None of them read all barcodes. But Zbar for IOS reading all the same codes.I think its the problem with hardware of the device.Is there any Scanner App better than above mentioned ?

Bar code Image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VR9I.jpg

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn about how to structure questions for this site. This is not a general discussion site, so "any comments about this?" is not a suitable question.

Comment: Start by posting basic information -- like, what barcode you are talking about!

Comment: @Sean Owen Link for Barcode added. Its a standard Barcode.Working with Iphone but not with android phones or tablet like samsung galaxy tab,HTC EVO 3D etc.

Comment: Both of those barcodes scan as UPC_E in ZXing Barcode Scanner. The first came out as 14302374 and the second was 19928326.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Thanks for the quick reply.But How you set it as a UPC_E Scanner.I have looked the settings there is no option for that. Also which device you are using?

Comment: @reji I just started Barcode Scanner from its shortcut icon, and pointed it at your picture. I didn't set up anything special. I have a DROID RAZR MAXX running 4.0.4.

Comment: They are not UPC-E, you're getting false positives. This is RSS-14

Answer (score 1):

This barcode is a form of RSS-14. zxing / Barcode Scanner reads it, but it's not the easiest to read. You need to put the image in landscape orientation (right side up). Try TRY_HARDER mode, and restrict your scan to the RSS-14 format to avoid false positives.

Comment: Maybe You are right .but still its not working for me.Anyway thanks for your valuable time